# Proper way of using grunt-bump and grunt-ng-constant together

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

While seemingly the tasks execute in proper order (bump first and than ngconstant creating a config file based on package.json-s version property) i think they actually execute parallely, and ngconstant reads up the package.json before bump has written it.

```
Running "bump" task
md
>> Version bumped to 2.0.6 (in package.json)

Running "ngconstant:production" (ngconstant) task
Creating module config at app/scripts/config.js...OK
```

The resultung package.json has 2.0.6 as version while config.js has 2.0.5.

My ngconstant config simply uses

```
grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
```

to read up the json.

So, basically the question is, how can i make sure that bump's write is finished, before reading up the json with ngconstant, and what actually causes the above?

**EDIT**: the original Gruntfile: https://github.com/dekztah/sc2/blob/18acaff22ab027000026311ac8215a51846786b8/Gruntfile.js

**EDIT**: the updated Gruntfile that solves the problem: https://github.com/dekztah/sc2/blob/e7985db6b95846c025ba0b615bf239c4f9c11e8f/Gruntfile.js

Comment: Please, post your `Gruntfile.js` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per grunt-ng-constant documentation:

> Or if you want to calculate the constants value at runtime you can create a lazy evaluated method which should be used if you generate your json file during the build process.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ngconstant: {
    options: {
      dest: 'dist/module.js',
      name: 'someModule'
    },
    dist: {
      constants: function () {
        return {
          lazyConfig: grunt.file.readJSON('build/lazy-config.json')
        };
      }
    }
  },
})
```

This forces the json to be read while the task runs, instead of when grunt inits the ngconstant task.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `package.json` file is stored in memory and is not updated before your run the next task.

An [workaround](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump/issues/47) would be to create a script in your file `package.json` as:

```
  "scripts": {
    "bumb-and-ngconstant": "grunt:bump && grunt:build"
  }
```

Comment: you are right about it being in memory. thanks for pointing that out.
while this is a good and working workaround, i have posted another answer which maybe a better solution for others